# Duplicate Element Error MongoDB .Net Core 3.0

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm working on integrating MongoDB into a C# project and have run into an issue I can't find a solution to.  The code is from an Xunit test class.  I'm first creating a simple Bson object, then inserting it into my collection.  This works.  Then I'm querying for the record to ensure it's in the collection.  At this point, I get a System.InvalidOperationException : Duplicate element name 'title' error.

Here's my mock Bson:

```
    // Create mock List<Bson Document>
    public class MongoUtilsBson : IEnumerable<object[]>
    {
        BsonDocument bson = new BsonDocument();
        List<BsonDocument> bsonList = new List<BsonDocument>();

        public MongoUtilsBson()
        {
            bson.Add("id", "TestId");
            bson.Add("title", "Test Title");
            bson.Add("owners", new BsonArray() { "TestOwner" });
            bson.Add("modifiedDate", "TestDate");

            bsonList.Add(bson);
        }

        public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
        {
            yield return new object[] { bsonList };
        }



        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Here's my test class:

```
    public class SheetsDataConverterTest
    {
        [Theory]
        [ClassData(typeof(MongoUtilsBson))]
        public async Task MongoInsertShouldInsertToSheetsDataCollection(List<BsonDocument> bsonDocuments)
        {

            // Arrange
            SheetsDataConverter.MongoInsert(bsonDocuments).Wait(); // Run synchronously

            // Act
            MongoDBConnect mongoDBConnect = new MongoDBConnect("GoogleExchange");
            var result = await mongoDBConnect.DataSelectAsync(@"{}", "SheetsData");

            // Assert
            Assert.True(result.Count == 1);

            // Cleanup
            await mongoDBConnect.DataDeleteAsync(@"{ id : ""TestId"" }", "SheetsData");


        }
    }
```

Here's the SheetsDataConverter class (this is specifying parameters for use between calling method and Mongo connection class):

```
    public static class SheetsDataConverter
    {
        public static async Task MongoInsert(List<BsonDocument> bsonDocuments)
        {
            SheetsDataClassMap.Register();
            List<SheetsDataModel> insertDocuments = new List<SheetsDataModel>();
            var m = UtilitiesFactory.ConnectMongo("GoogleExchange");

            foreach (BsonDocument doc in bsonDocuments)
            {
                BsonDocument cleanDoc = MongoUtils.bsonClean(doc); // Remove periods from key names

                SheetsDataModel sdm = new SheetsDataModel()
                {
                    id = cleanDoc.GetElement("id").Value.AsString,
                    Title = cleanDoc.GetElement("title").Value.AsString,
                    owners = cleanDoc.GetElement("owners").Value.AsBsonArray,
                    modifiedDate = cleanDoc.GetElement("modifiedDate").Value.AsString,
                    extraElements = cleanDoc.AsBsonDocument
                };
                insertDocuments.Add(sdm);
            }

            int result = await m.DataUpsertManyAsync("SheetsData", insertDocuments);
        }
    }
```

There's a class map that's used to orient the data being inserted, but not being referenced on the `FindAsync(query)` method.

Class map:

```
    public class SheetsDataClassMap
    {
        public static void Register()
        {
            if (!BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(SheetsDataModel)))
            {
                BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<SheetsDataModel>(cm =>
                {
                    cm.AutoMap();
                    cm.SetIsRootClass(true);
                    cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.id).SetElementName("id");
                    cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.Title).SetElementName("title");
                    cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.owners).SetElementName("owners");
                    cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.modifiedDate).SetElementName("modifiedDate");
                    cm.MapExtraElementsMember(c => c.extraElements);
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

The record is inserted properly, but when `await mongoDBConnect.DataSelectAsync(@"{}", "SheetsData");` is called, the method gives the error.

The method called:

```
        public async Task<List<BsonDocument>> DataSelectAsync(string query, string collection)
        {
            IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> coll = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collection);

            var result = await coll.FindAsync(query); // Fails here

            List<BsonDocument> list = result.ToList();

            return list;
        }
```

I can use a find function in Compass and in the Mongo shell to get the record out so I don't know what's wrong with the record that .Net won't parse it.  Since .Net inserted it and the duplicate entries context is set to false, it shouldn't have any duplicated elements at all.  I can post a record directly into the collection and get the record back out through .Net so I suspect it's got something to do with my class map.  However, when interrogating the Bson, there's no duplication in the record.

Here's the stack trace:

```
  Message: 
    System.InvalidOperationException : Duplicate element name 'title'.
  Stack Trace: 
    BsonDocument.Add(BsonElement element)
    BsonDocument.Add(String name, BsonValue value)
    BsonDocumentSerializer.DeserializeValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    BsonValueSerializerBase`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context)
    CursorBatchDeserializationHelper.DeserializeBatch[TDocument](RawBsonArray batch, IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings)
    FindCommandOperation`1.CreateCursorBatch(BsonDocument commandResult)
    FindCommandOperation`1.CreateCursor(IChannelSourceHandle channelSource, BsonDocument commandResult)
    FindCommandOperation`1.ExecuteAsync(RetryableReadContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    FindOperation`1.ExecuteAsync(RetryableReadContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    FindOperation`1.ExecuteAsync(IReadBinding binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    OperationExecutor.ExecuteReadOperationAsync[TResult](IReadBinding binding, IReadOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    MongoCollectionImpl`1.ExecuteReadOperationAsync[TResult](IClientSessionHandle session, IReadOperation`1 operation, ReadPreference readPreference, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSessionAsync[TResult](Func`2 funcAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    MongoDBConnect.DataSelectAsync(String query, String collection) line 26
    SheetsDataConverterTest.MongoInsertShouldInsertToSheetsDataCollection(List`1 bsonDocuments) line 23
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to correct the issue.  The issue was the collection declaration in the DataSelectAsync method.  I was bringing the data in as a Bson object which was failing during deserialization.

Old code:

```
        public async Task<List<BsonDocument>> DataSelectAsync(string query, string collection)
        {
            IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> coll = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collection)
```

New code:

```
        public async Task<List<T>> DataSelectAsync<T>(string query, string collection, T classData) where T : class
        {
            IMongoCollection<T> coll = db.GetCollection<T>(collection);
```

The generic declaration of the collection type sends the results through the class map and bypasses the Bson deserialization.